# POSTing large amounts of data with HTTParty

Tags: ruby, json, rest, httparty

I'm using HTTParty to post information to a server using the following code:

```
this_component = {"name" => "something", "ip" => "localhost", "logs" => logs_to_push}
payload = {"payload" => JSON.dump(this_component)}
response = JSONClient.post("http://localhost:8080/log", :body => '', :query => payload)
```

The problem is that I get a `Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET)` message when the POST actually executes, which I'm pretty sure is caused by my payload being too large (as `logs_to_push` is an array with ~200 log lines in it). How would I refactor the above so that I could push this data successfully?

Answer (score 3):

So it turns out that for large amount of stuff, you should put the payload in `:body` and not `:query`. For future people that run into this problem, the correct code (working off the above example) would be:

```
this_component = {"name" => "something", "ip" => "localhost", "logs" => logs_to_push}
payload = {"body" => {"payload" => JSON.dump(this_component)}}
response = JSONClient.post("http://localhost:8080/log", payload)
```

Comment: This is actually not related to HTTParty but of the server where the request is sent to. What the maximum length is depends on the server software. See some values in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string

Answer (score 1):

Try This for Post Req

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

load = {:name => "xyz",:logs => "xyz"}
payload = load.to_json
url="http://xyz.com/abc"
response = HttParty.post(url,{:body => payload})
```

Thanks