# How to figure out the data limit of a patch request (in Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, httprequest

I'm updating a kite resource via a rails 4 API using a patch request.  Each kite has a name and a description.  For the sake of argument, let's say a description can be as long as the length of a term paper.  I've noticed that when I update kites with short descriptions via patch, everything is fine.  When it's much longer, the update doesn't seem to occur and there's no evidence from the logs that the update method that the patch request routes to is called.  Here's the log output (sanitized) when the patch is working:

```
[30/Jul/2014 09:40:58] "PATCH /1/kites/5?name=JaneKite&description=20%02l0_rt2%22iyp0s%2d%2%%i2%bA2%D2%20t%22%%2%%02mc%i02a0e2Aae2%0AE%0va%a2i20o00a%0c%i2A2s00nlsi2%%%2%iCenr0A200%222A%h2te%0c20l2222%%CA2m2aCgtohr2g02%C22sy2o0%0AC%s2A%0nrna%uc0t22%tcss%00sa%2a0%e0%2%%%C20a%0020l0022%rAuC002eu%c0%%0r%_oeeclr%ys%D20on0%t0r%S0l%0%%2a%02oA2p2220%%2A2%a%0c00%rn0%e2022-0Ca2&r00eetilc0%2%90220n0%%2000002%%%%e2%02020rl2222220000022C220_V2oyi%0%0avf2r20I00%gat2o%e%i0%0D%e2l.22a20oS0vlC20022%2sAce20inc.232oD-e25o22a20l2%%0nef%%0-%n020t20222%0ro22%es%0%so2e20b1o22n%0en00%o2%%%s%0k%0s_%0A20%T%%hd0nA0e0224if0I2%a0A0n0os2l001tud%0%%tm0uf2I%2n2%NeGB%M2A2y200ct22l0u%o2a%2e202a%220B0002ntdsna22r_r0%%%22%tA2i2ecsBB%Do020p=2at0i2%0gs0020%%2%%%%p%a2200s%2AtrUr20C2up02%20lyD%i20a20g0o0n%2t0ia0a2y'00%22T%%02f%%lb_u2Il%nl0sa0M4C%0%a00%S%0220le0e%0r200A0H0t0t%22f0%%a0002e2022cT222i02a%t%d%%2ttAt20%A22e0%%02%_0vB0p0dode2020%i%i=%0RD0Fa0%eee20%as2mCt2c2i%n%tac0c2%ul%200%%%0%%%%0r%00iA0FM%2e%l%i0%2%0%02sa%%o2%c%a0222%i0a2ttt%2N0200or)i%evs0%%220%0n00d0t02c2o02g2i%_2n%0t2%0ei22%sr%e3Tee%sS%20%ttD%%v%e%2020a%2%oi%iD%2ioU2n0sCs%eerc0%a020%v%0n2o2e%2a2t%000A000o00m%ei%22t2%%e%0a0yo22s%02An0I20%&u0i2%0e0e%2ypu02%%2hx0a_0=ht%0n%2e%t.0002i2aia21%222t%%02t2ha00%2%0%w%250%%%%et&rD%y2he0D2%u%2e%RS%C0%n2oD22r00Annp%fua0220%0A%002o202%%02SD%o%0m%Di20%u0ac2%D00sLa2s222%%%22rn%e%%%d02%=%2200%(rr=%20ac%0o220r20_v2%y%do%noPlsA%Nro2t%000%02%0220%C%%0%0%%c%gC022222ls2D00sf0202t3c%He02%a00s%%0v%2%b02e%020a%l%2si%20%0r20rn0u%nt%te%%2U%o02elu0c%%i%%%00%02a%t%e%%2A222l%0020il%%000i00%02an22002re0%20a020C2%Nstcn%2i2g0tr0Tl_%%2s22a0ls2s-DgiaPen1e%0a2s0c0Dd%00re0%%S%00%00%ilo%_n%%2a0%i00o0u%000%20mre%0P00%%2%0m0tC2oeD2%%%a2D0s%2%usC%%02Ai%0220a20m2Ds2re%i0%l%a%iy0%2%P00%%t0s000%n%od%2&020lc&%%l%st%e%n%23%2%00ep0as00oat20l0%03%%%i%%2uio%Sr0%%r0%u%nt0o%a%%%2%022C%%%o20t%%0%o0A%%0iC%%00og%a02%%gtl00002%D22fl%%00im2%20&ue2c0rno%_20%%2%n%22aehe02a.daeDAtPec%a0t%ter2nsa%2rAn%0st%0l32etc%a2t0i%c2%0%2%%g0e2%0Al00r%%2y02D0e2u002%220ie00%0i2%2%2a22o2ts%a0ir%e20r22%Du0e21ita%Pnt%eM%nu0%5%0%l%0caf%%%2%22002i2nc02t20Tlncm%nsDA.0l1i0%22%ro2202_riDr2l0Ap0222%0e%2tme%20%%u2pn22%202vs0C2%020%00%0pDrar2o2%%0%f22%s&ro%tr22%0i0.2%ta0%22%%%20c%220nsfrrc0ital%02_0%c22%%o 22Au2o%2%0%%2C%&%niieram%2H0220.20A00%C%020us2%n0sa20nrtae%oo0S2%i%e0t0ea%rv00l0%0e2%r=22e00eB5e2%202lt2fh2%%2a2ld2N2%02%2%0002%gTa0%s2L22g2%2s2%B20i%aeSUese0r0t022a2%in0r02%20%tss02&2ati2%ss0on2%023i%9%iau000AD0200ns%20e0r0%f%iSc2=0%2c0m2D2c222s0%Af%202%s20202%3%000n%At%0a2trs%20Dd%%ad2iln00t2n2A0o%0%%L0aLmiA00A0c%Dgd22g2%%l0200U0r%%%i0yNe%n020ilu%%000e0i%y2o%l%50Uem%2002a%%0%00%di2.2e0t%o5%u%2oeSi02000H%%i2t%r%D%s%0i0%2redy22P0g%0&%22D22e202%0sn%e20222%ie0i%00Dn220sa2%2%&u%2tb2%a%2h%sC022b02rl0v%t%%s_202%020%%0=020%40%%0hsr2eo02%tv%20s%r2b00%a2220%%r%A0F2.co%2i2le=%tr20%I%2%%r%A%0cri%%a2%%c20%%%0&D9Aruv%kn0%0i2%0220ee%2teag2ts%o2u0t200oA%S%i0%%=00l0%%%=2f00n20tah0%tna%2e%yt%0Dny2c0rp%%%g%02%D020o%0c022%t0eo2i02%c009te0di22ca222ice00%20%c0A2A2tA0%nn2acErD0mtMDth0022%2%%222%0s0D2i2%0%0%y%e2202%2%20e0r022%s20on%%0lc2-00%2%sll0002=%ft%0%.us22%0b%f%=ilC00iDa%%0%%%i%02p%oyc2An20oh02d20tet%%0a022%2t2s%&20%%%0t%0%%02i22pea0ut2222%5%l%soroi%l20%a2P22ld%mGtnr%1ey0220cn20r0%20%i%N%%00%0tcm0%n%igo%%lis20
HTTP/1.1" 500 22197 13.7511
```

1) Is it a data size limit or a URL size limit, and if so, how do I figure out the limit?
2)  Can I get around the limit by doing a POST request, which as far as I can tell has no data size limit?

EDIT:

I'm using HTTParty gem

```
   response = HTTParty.post(url,{:body => payload})
```

Comment: URL size limits vary per browser (2048 chars for some ie versions) and can also depend on proxies etc. in between you and the remote host

Comment: One way to at least up your data limit is to use POST and use the body payload: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170977/posting-large-amounts-of-data-with-httparty

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the description in the PATCH request body, and not in the url?

Comment: zetetic, have to test it out to know the answer to your question (I suspect the answer is I'm passing it in the URL), but would PATCH allow you to pass the description in the request body?

Comment: As it turns out doing HTTParty.post(url,{:query => payload}) is what was causing the description to be passed in the URL.  So the issue was I was violating the URL length limit.